# UseState not update when using alongside with redux dispatch in arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm making an app that have notes, and when develop the delete function, i faced this error, the useState do not update when use alongside with redux dispatch function ( even the redux function run, the useState do not run ) , i tried to create the same issue on codesandbox, but weird is it WORKING TOTALLY FINE ON WEB?!

Here is the code:

**NoteList.tsx**

```js
function NoteList(props: noteListI) {
  const { title, note, id, date, selectStatus } = props; //they are props
  const nav = useNavigation(); //for navigation
  const [isDeleteChecked, setDeleteChecked] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.persistedReducer.note); // note item from redux
  const toggleSelectedButton = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.toggle.enableSelectedButton
  ); // to show selected button icon

  const onNavDetail = () => {
    nav.navigate(RouteName.EDIT_NOTE, {
      date: date,
      note: note,
      header: title,
      id: id,
    });
  };
  const toggleSelectButton = () => {
    dispatch(switchToggle());
  }; // toggle delete button function
  const setDeleteItem = () => {
    setDeleteChecked(!isDeleteChecked);
    dispatch(toggleSelect({ id: id }));
  }; ////==>>> the issue here the 'setDeleteChecked' not even work

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onLongPress={() => {
        toggleSelectButton();
      }}
      style={CONTAINER}
      onPress={() => (!toggleSelectedButton ? onNavDetail() : setDeleteItem())}
    >
      <View style={NOTE_ITEM_CONTAINER}>
        <Text>{isDeleteChecked?.toString()}</Text> ==>always false, why????!
        <View>
          <View row centerV style={HEADER_CONTAINER}>
            <View>
              <AppText bold style={HEADER_TEXT}>
                {title}
              </AppText>
            </View>

            {toggleSelectedButton && (
              <View>
                {selectStatus ? ( ===> this is from redux and work but slow
                  <CheckIcon name="checkcircle" size={size.iconSize} />
                ) : (
                  <CheckIcon name="checkcircleo" size={size.iconSize} />
                )}
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
          <View style={NOTE_CONTAINER}>
            <AppText numberOfLines={7}>{note}</AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            alignSelf: "flex-end",
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <AppText>{moment(date).format("h:mmA MMM Do YY")}</AppText>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
export default memo(NoteList);
```

I use these from flatlist, here is the main flatlist code:

```js
export default function NoteListScreen() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>();
  const nav = useNavigation();
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   dispatch(loadDefault());
  // }, []);
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.persistedReducer.note);
  const userInfo: user = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.persistedReducer.firebase.userInfomation
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchNote(userInfo.email)); //fetch note from firebase
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={CONTAINER}>
      {data.length === 0 ? (
        <>
          <ScrollView>
            <HeaderNote />
            <AppText style={EMPTY_NOTE}>
              Hmm, so don't have any secret yet
            </AppText>
          </ScrollView>
          <FooterNote />
        </>
      ) : (
        <View style={CONTAINER}>
          <FlatList
            removeClippedSubviews
            data={data}
            style={{
              marginBottom:
                Platform.OS === "ios"
                  ? onePercentHeight * 15
                  : onePercentHeight * 12,
            }}
            keyExtractor={() => {
              return (
                new Date().getTime().toString() +
                Math.floor(
                  Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime())
                ).toString()
              );
            }}
            ListHeaderComponent={() => <HeaderNote />}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <NoteList  ==> here , the note list that faced error
                  note={item.note}
                  title={item.header}
                  date={item.date}
                  id={item.id}
                  selectStatus={item.selectStatus}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
          <FooterNote />
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Here is the reducer code:

```
const noteReducer = createSlice({
  name: "note",
  initialState: NoteList,
  reducers: {
    addNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      const newNote: NoteI = {
        id:
          new Date().getTime().toString() +
          Math.floor(
            Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime())
          ).toString(),
        header: action.payload.header,
        note: action.payload.note,
        date: new Date(),
        selectStatus: false,
      };
      state.push(newNote);
    },
  
    toggleSelect: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          return { ...item, selectStatus: !item.selectStatus };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },   ///========>This is the reducer using in the note function
    loadDefault: (state) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, selectStatus: false };
      });
    },
    resetNote: (state) => {
      return (state = []);
    },

    editNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            note: action.payload.note,
            header: action.payload.header,
            date: action.payload.date,
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
  
    builder.addCase(fetchNote.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = [];
      return state.concat(action.payload);
    });
    
  },
});
```

Here is the image of what i'm talking about, the code in image from `noteList.tsx`, the first piece of code i post here
[image]

Here is the quick gif:
[image]

In above gif, the false must return true then false everytime i click ( as above code ) but i don't why it never change value, the black dot also change color because it use value using in the same function using with this value, but when `setDeleteItem` fire, it NOT fire the `setDeleteChecked(!isDeleteChecked)`

Here is the demo that i made, but it WORK TOTALLY FINE, but in my app, it make weird error https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-neumann-0497v?file=/redux/some-redux.tsx

Please help, i'm trying to provide must as i can, i stuck for days for this, thank you so much, if you need any detail, just tell me

Comment: Did you tried setting state like this? `setDeleteChecked(prev => !prev)`?